# __NSCFConstantString objectForKey unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I basically get this error

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x581f0'
```

on my program. I think it refers to this call I make,

```
if (data != nil) {
    if([data objectForKey:@"username"]){
       // NSArray *check= [[NSArray alloc]init];
        //check=[data allValues];
        [dict setObject:[data allValues] forKey:@"args"];

    }else{
    [dict setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:data] forKey:@"args"];
}
```

at the setObject:[data allValues]. I don't know why it gives that error but data is an NSDictionary and I'm getting all the values and placing it in an array.

Comment: Right after "if (data != nil)", log [data class] and see what it gives.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks for the tip man. It showed the problem. At first it returns NSMutableDictionary then a string. So my question now is, is there a way to check whether something is anSDictionary or not?

Comment: How about if([data isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks man. I had already found it online but thanks again.

Comment: Seems like a design flaw that you are calling this method with an NSString where an NSDictionary is expected.

Answer (score 3):

Is the error happening here:

```
    if([data objectForKey:@"username"]){
```

I assume so, as that is the only place objectForKey seems to be called.  You are calling it on a variable called 'data', which i'm guessing simply is not a dictionary.  You should NSLog its type to see.

Comment: @darren Yeah it first returned a _NSDictionaryM and then after a string. This actually goes back to what I originally wanted. Is there a way to check that the value you are using is a NSDictionary?

Comment: There are ways to check, sure. But your situation sounds like a nasty memory problem (if I am understanding this right).  Are you saying sometimes when you log you get a dictionary and sometimes you get a string?  That kind of bug sometimes implies an overrelease of aj object (are you using arc?).  The runtime is deallocating your original dictionary and using that old space to put a new string object.

Comment: If you really do want to check what type 'data' is, you would do something like if ([data isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] )